# How to run White + Teamcity (Winforms application)

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm trying to run UI-tests (written using white). When I run them using NUnitConsole everything works fine. When I try to run them using TeamCity I get the following exception `Test(s) failed. White.Core.UIItems.UIActionException : Couldn't find window with title Form1 in process 4132, after waiting for 5000 ms`. What might be wrong? What could I do to make the test pass?

Comment: Is the agent running as admin?

Comment: Yes, i tried to run it as admin. Doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried logging into the server once using the admin account (e.g. with Remote Desktop)? Sometimes you need to allow Windows to first establish the user profile for it to access the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does the build agent need to be set to interact with the desktop, but the desktop must be displayed in order for UI automation to work - desktop cannot be locked and screen saver must not be running. Is your agent on a headless machine? If you are using RDP to connect to the agent to check on things, when you close RDP, it locks the desktop. In this case, the automation will fail. Instead of using RDP, use a VNC viewer to log on to the box, rather than RDP, as VNC will not lock the desktop when you close it.

Another issue to consider is network access. If you are running TC agent as a service with access to desktop, then it  will be running under service account which will not have access to network shares, etc... If this is a probelm, then you will not be able to run TC agent as a service, and will instead need to logon with a domain user and kick off the agent.bat file to start the agent.

Answer (score 3):

Spent a lot of time solving this issue.

**Main steps:**

1. You need separate computer with teamcity build agend installed on it. Computer should have monitor and mouse.
2. The agent SHOULD NOT be launched and run as a Windows service (disable it if needed).
3. You should launch TeamCity build agent from .bat file (as administrator). To do this go to `TeamCityBuildAgentfolder\bin` and launch `agent.bat` file with `start` argument
4. Disable computer's screen sleep/lock after certain period of time. Your tests will require desktop for UI manipulations.

If you done everything right you should be able to see your build agent active in TeamCity's "Agents" menu.

**You can also automate TeamCity agent launch (at selected user's logon):**

5. Automate user's logon. More instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/624576/windows-8-auto-login)
6. Create task in Task Scheduler which will launch build agent at user's logon with administrative rights (with highest privileges)
7. Make sure that the user who will logon automatically has all neccessary permissions (run the scripts, perform file operations etc.)

**IMPORTANT!**

- Running UI tests in such way is a potential security hole so make sure that the non-authorized people have no acccess to computer that runs this tests.
- Remember that for running your UI test the computer SHOULD NOT be locked or be in sleep mode.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to make the Teamcity build agent interact with desktop.

Run -> services.msc -> Select TeamCity Build agent and right click -> Properties -> Log On tab -> Check "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Edit:

If that doesn't work, stop the agent service, go to Build Agent folder ( c:\teamcity\buildagent\bin ? ) and issue `agent.bat start` and then trigger the tests.

Comment: @StuffHappens can you try stopping the agent service and starting it manually from the agent folder i.e run it from console and then triggering the tests?

Comment: This may sound silly, but does a window with a title "Form1" actually exist at the time the test is running ?

Comment: @manojlds i understand it works fine with NUnitConsole, I was asking what is *exactly* happening when executing from TeamCity - is the window created and White cannot access it? is it not created at all? If (for some reason that i cannot yet explain) the window is not created at all, White will not be able to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is [recommendation](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20with%20Continuous%20Integration&referringTitle=Home) to run the UI tests on virtual machines.

Seems as most reliable solution.